# Using method from a library

Tags: c++

I am a bit new to working with external libs, bear with me.

I am getting error when I try to use function `SetCommType` from some SDK.
I included header, linked to `lib` and `dll` is also available at run time.

This is error:

```
"error C2065: 'byte' : undeclared identifier"
```

This is (SDK) header file, where the editor navigates once I click the error:

```
/*------define windows version---- */
#ifndef _WINDOWS_VERSION
#define _WINDOWS_VERSION
#endif


#ifdef _WINDOWS_VERSION
    #ifdef CV_API_EXPORT
      #define extern__stdcall extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall
    #else
  ->#define extern__stdcall extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall<-
    #endif
#else
    #define extern__stdcall extern int 
    typedef unsigned char byte;
    typedef unsigned char BYTE;
#endif




extern__stdcall SetCommType(byte aType); // here it complains
```

In the `ifdef` section, actually everything except the line where I put `->` and `<-` is grayed out, maybe that is the problem why it can't see `byte`? (and other errors follow then I believe because of this).

I am not sure what I did wrong.
I included header in Cpp file, added lib to dependencies and dll is available to use.
Once I tried using the method: `SetCommType`, I got this error.

Comment: Have you tried `#include`ing `windoes.h`?

Comment: @RSahu: you mean <windows.h>? doesn't help. Actually you could have noticed this: `"#ifndef _WINDOWS_VERSION
#define _WINDOWS_VERSION
#endif"`. So `_WINDOWS_VERSION` should be defined? :confused:

Comment: Yes, given the posted code, `_WINDOWS_VERSION` is defined, which means that `byte` won't be. Yet the prototype for `SetCommType` seems to depend on `byte` being defined. I would declare this header file broken...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the SDK file is sloppy. In its windows specific part, it should have:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS_VERSION
    #include <windows.h>
    #ifdef CV_API_EXPORT
      #define extern__stdcall extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall
    #else
    #define extern__stdcall extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall
    #endif
#else
    #define extern__stdcall extern int 
    typedef unsigned char byte;
    typedef unsigned char BYTE;
#endif
```

To get around the problem, add

```
#include <windows.h>
```

in your `.cc` file before the line that includes the SDK header file.

Comment: @R Sahu: I can't modify the header I guess? It's not mine. Now that I followed your suggestion I get this error: "CNAFire.lib : fatal error LNK1136: invalid or corrupt file" -- do you have any idea why? This is the lib for the SDK

Comment: @dmcr_code I can't help you with the linker error. That is something you'll have to take it up to the people who created the SDK or somebody that has used it before.

Comment: alright thanks. So `windows.h` contains `byte` that is the catch?

Answer (score 0):

The typedef's for byte and BYTE probably shouldn't be wrapped in the preprocessor #if's like that, OR, the header should be including the declaration of byte/BYTE from another header (which it currently is not).

If the library is yours, solve it by moving the typedefs or by adding an include in the _WINDOWS_VERSION case that will define the types.

If the library is NOT yours, the creator probably expects Windows.h to be included *before* you include the SDK header so that that the byte/BYTE is defined, which ultimately should be included within the SDK header.

A good header file declares everything needed to use it, and nothing more, using forward declarations whenever possible.

*Now I see that angle brackets made Windows.h disappear.

Comment: the library is not mine. So I didn't follow what to do exactly in such case?

Comment: I meant exactly what R Sahu said in his answer, I guess mine wasn't quite clear though.

Comment: "Now I see that angle brackets made Windows.h disappear." yes, I think that was the issue :( :))